# Loader/spinner animantion while route is changing

Tags: angularjs

How can I show a spinner or loader gif animation while route is changing from one to another.

I am using ng view like as follows:

```
 <div ng-view class="view-animate">
 </div>
```

I am loading templates from server and also inline. While the HTTP request is pending I need to show the spinner/loader... any snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show and hide the loader when location change starts and is completed, respectively. 
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QWxYBvrFY1pkq1EDBbEw?p=preview) is a plunkr that I have created for this situation. This uses ui-router and is taken from one of the apps that I have created, so it may not be useful as-is, but it will give you an idea on how to approach the problem.

HTML Code inserted below just to keep SO happy...

```
<ui-view class="view"></ui-view>
<div loader="" class="ng-hide"></div>
```

I hope it helps.
Abhi.

Comment: It would be nice if you could just say whether my solution helped or not!

Comment: i used  $routeProvider rather than  $stateProvider , i modified states $routeChangeStart,$routeChangeSuccess,$routeChangeError according to my need

Comment: Great!! I am glad to be of help!!

Comment: You should not paste code "just to keep SO happy" but paste relevant code to explain and improve your answer... Nice plunker though

Comment: can you paste the route change logic?